# Is CPLEX able to find "just" A feasible solution?

Tags: cplex

Is it possible to solve a problem with CPLEX without objective (i.e. just finding a feasible solution that fits all the constraints ) or with a "silly" objective (min0)?

Comment: Yes, it is possible (and legitimate). By default, if you don't define an objective it will be a minimization problem and all objective coefficients will be zero. This is easy to test; you should give it a try as an exercise.

Comment: For a given problem, I guess I will find different feasible solutions from one run to another ? @rkersh

Comment: By default, the results should be deterministic. See the [parallel mode switch](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.7.1/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/Parameters/topics/ParallelMode.html) parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You have an example in `CPLEX_Studio1271\opl\examples\opl\color`.